# uart.on("data", ... not firing withoug "\r\n" (0x0d 0x0a)

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I am currently writing drivers for indoor air quality sensors (CO2 and particulate matter) in lua for the NodeMCU firmware.

The sensors are connected via the alternative UART pins GPIO13/15. On issuing a measure command, the ESP switches uart.alt(1) and registers a uart.on("data", 9, ...) function for firing after nine bytes are received. I have tested this with two ch340 connected to native and alternative UART pins.
The reading of the values is fine if i manually enter the data and add \r\n (0d 0a).

However my used sensors do not have \r\n at the end of their replies - how can I change my code to read out the UART buffer after 9 bytes received?

```
function MHZ19:measure(callback)
-- timeout and restore UART
tmr.alarm(self.timer, self.timeout*1000, 0,
function()
    uart.alt(0)
    uart.setup(0, 115200, 8, uart.PARITY_NONE, uart.STOPBITS_1, 1)
    uart.on('data')
    print("Timed out. Restored UART.")
    callback(nil)
end)

uart.on('data', 9,
    function(data)
        -- unregister uart.on callback
        uart.on('data')
        tmr.stop(self.timer)
        uart.alt(0)
        uart.setup(0, 115200, 8, uart.PARITY_NONE, uart.STOPBITS_1, 1)
        -- First two bytes are control bytes 0xFF && 0x86
        local a,b = string.byte(data,1,2)
        if (a==tonumber('FF',16)) and (b==tonumber('86',16)) then
            local high,low = string.byte(data,3,4)
            local co2value = high * 256 + low
            callback(co2value)
        else
            callback(nil)
        end
    end)

    uart.alt(self.altUart)
    uart.setup(0, 9600, 8, uart.PARITY_NONE, uart.STOPBITS_1, 0)

    -- Send request sequence to get value (refer to datasheet)
    -- send: FF 01 86 00 00 00 00 00 79
    -- receive: FF 86 02 E8 42 04 2B 1C 03
    uart.write(0, 0xff, 0x01, 0x86, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x79)
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [NodeMCU Documentation](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/uart/#uarton) the `uart.on()` command accepts an optional parameter `[run_input]`. 
If this parameter is set to 1, the interpreter will wait for '\r' or '\n' and then run the command.
Setting this parameter to 0 and setting the amount of bytes to be received, invokes the callback function on retrieval of the specified amounts of bytes.

This solved my problem.

Comment: Hi Vlad, sure - as for the above mentioned function, which is used to write a command out to a CO2 sensor via UART and then wait for the answer from the sensor. Simply put in the second argument to uart.on (in this case the '0' after '... end, ' `uart.on('data', 9, function(data) print(data) end, 0)`

Comment: did I get it right there must be module introduction before function, i.e. `local MHZ19 = {timer = 1, timeout = 1, altUart = 0}`, usage is `MHZ19 = require("MHZ19")`? which nodemcu dev board pins did you attach to tr/rx? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you got that right. You can take a look at the lua-module examples in the nodemcu repository. For pin assignment, the nodemcu docs for the uart module describe the alternative gpios. I think they were 14 and 15 but I do not know tonwhich pins of the nodemcu board that translates to.